# Specifications Pattern crossing bounded context - Domain Driven Design

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, specifications

I'm trying to understand and implement with good practice the Specification Pattern within my domain driven design project.

I have few questions:

For example: verifying that a customer is subscribed before update a data on a aggregate is it part of business rule and should sit in the domain layer?

Can specifications cross bounded context? For exemple, i have a Subscription bounded context where we can find a specification called SubscriptionIsActive. In a second bounded context let's call it PropertyManagement. I would like to call SubscriptionIsActive specification as an User need to be a subscriber to create a Property aggregate. My specification here is crossing bounded context and i don't think it's right choice, any recommandation, tips?

Where should instanciate the specification when we want to use it, Application layer (that contains, commands and query, we use cqrs) or Domain Layer wihtin the aggregate root?

At the end, where should access control like (User has rights to edit some aggregate) sit in a domain driven design, Domain Layer or Application Layer in services before calling the aggregate?

Thanks